# Publishing an App with same Name, same Package Name but should be displayed in two different countries?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to publish one Android App on google Playstore to two different countries with some modifications but having same App name and also same package name.Is this possible in Android.
The requirement is

1)I will publish one app on playstore which should be displayed to only one country then

2)Will do some modifications in the same app and want to publish the same app on the playstore which should be displayed to different country.

Thanks.

Comment: Read this similar issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338465/possible-to-deploy-two-different-android-apps-as-upgrades-to-an-app-already-depl

Comment: I am also having same problem, Did you find any solution?